Does it make sense to extend the definition of the ideal quotient to modules?
So, just for a bit of context, I'm trying to learn commutative algebra and right now I'm trying to look at interesting operations for combining ideals to make new ideals. I don't have an understanding of what the ordinary ideal quotient is for.
However, the definition of an ideal quotient seems to extend to modules without trouble and the annihilator, a special case for this notation, is defined for arbitrary modules (for example in Noncommutative algebra by Farb and Dennis on page 6).
Does it make sense to extend the notion of an ideal quotient to modules?
Wikipedia does not mention extending ideal quotients to modules, which makes me think that this construction straight up doesn't work (or doesn't produce an ideal in general).
I'm almost certain I'm missing something, because if the notion of an ideal quotient generalized to modules, one of the sources I've looked at would have said something. Of my arguments below, I'm most skeptical of the argument about addition, I'm pretty sure that $(M:K)$ would at least give me a multiplicatively closed subset of my ring $A$.

The definition of the ideal quotient given in Atiyah-Macdonald on page 8 (unlike the authors I'll use $\subset$ in place of $\subseteq$):
Let $A$ be a commutative unital ring, here's the definition of the ideal quotient.
$$ (a : b) := \{ x \in A : xb \subset a \} $$
This does not appear to use the fact that $a$ and $b$ are ideals, rather than just submodules in an essential way. I think one can define the ideal quotient of submodules as follows, provided that $M$ and $K$ are both submodules of a third submodule $L$ (asking questions like $xM \subset K$ is not possible unless we have some shared context for comparing elements of $M$ and $K$).
$$ (M : K) := \{ x \in A : xK \subset M \} $$
I will now prove that $(M : K)$ defines an ideal.
Let $x$ and $r$ elements of the ring $A$, since $rxK \subset xK$, it holds that $rxK \subset x K \subset M$ and hence $rxK \subset M$. Thus $(M:K)$ is closed under multiplication by an arbitrary ring element.
Let $x$ and $y$ be arbitrary elements of $M$. Interpret $xk, yk, (x+y)k$ as expression denoting elements of $L$ (the shared module) and $\equiv_M$ as a two-place equivalence relation on $L$, which asserts that two elements are equivalent if and only if they differ by an element of $M$.
I want to show that 1 and 2 imply 3.

$\forall k \in K \mathop. xk \equiv_M 0$
$\forall k \in K \mathop. yk \equiv_M 0$
$\forall k \in K \mathop. (x+y)k \equiv_M 0$

Suppose $\forall k \in K \mathop. xk \equiv_M 0$ and suppose by way of contrapositive that for some $c$ in $K$, it holds that $(x+y)c \not\equiv_M 0$.
It holds that $xc \equiv_M 0$. Thus it holds that $((x+y)-x)c \not\equiv_M 0$. Thus $yc \not\equiv_M 0$, as desired.
Thus $(M:K)$ is an ideal.
I spot-checked this with $\mathbb{Z}$ as my ring, $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ as my $L$, and $\{0, 4, 8\}$ as $K$ and $\{0, 6\}$ as $M$,
multiplying $0, 4, 8$ by any multiple of three lands me in $M$, anything else doesn't, so $(M : K) = (3)$ in this case.

Yes, this is an ideal, it's the annihilator of the image of $K$ in $L/M$.

Atiyah and MacDonald make the same definition of $(N:P)$ for submodules $N,P$ in the last paragraph of p. 19.

@ViktorVaughn, right you are. I missed that.
